# How do I use the new hash style with numbers?

Tags: ruby

How do I use the new hash style with numbers as keys?

I have:

```
 { 1 => "terrible", 3=> "OK", 5 => "awesome" }
```

But I'd like to know how to write them using the new hash style.

Comment: You can't. There is no such thing as a "new hash syntax" for numeric keys. Ruby has introduced a new syntax explicitly for using symbols as keys. Any amount of reading should have given you this answer.

Comment: @meagar: *Certain* symbols, you can't use the JavaScript-style notation with symbols like `:$set`, `:'0'`, ... Yes, this is my pet peeve.

Comment: Yes, this is reserved for keys that are symbols, but could the designers of that feature have made it more general? Suppose `key: value` were interpreted as `{ key => value }` if `key.is_a? Object => true`, and as `{ :key => value }` if `key.is_a? Object` raised an "undefined local variable or method" exception. (What about `key.is_a? Object => false`?). Not advocating, just mulling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is a number, not a symbol. With the new hash style of `{key: value}` the key is always supposed to be a symbol, so you can't use the new hash style with your hash because your keys start with numbers, not symbols. See "[Update your entire project to Ruby 1.9 hash syntax](http://effectif.com/ruby/update-your-project-for-ruby-19-hash-syntax)" where it explicitly states:

> In version 1.9 Ruby introduced new syntax for hash literals **whose
>   keys are symbols.**

Comment: Technically symbols *can* start with a number; `:"123"` and `"123".to_sym` both produce a symbol composed of digits only.

Comment: Something like a = :1 will produce an error. What you're describing is a string data type, not a number.

Comment: Instead of saying "this link", use something descriptive for anchor text. See the W3's "[Link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text)" section, and "[Don't use "click here" as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"

Comment: @daremkd What meagar was describing are actually Symbols, however are you note those are not supported in the new Hash syntax. `:"123".class # => Symbol`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers FYI, that syntax will be supported for hashes in the next version of Ruby: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4276

Comment: You can wrap the numbers in double quotes and do :"Anything goes here" but that doesn't change the fact at the end they'll be symbols. I think there's a difference between the DATA TYPE and the CONTENT in the actual symbol data type. His question was whether he can use the new hash style with numbers as keys and the answer is not. Symbols types can be the only type of keys with the 1.9 new hash style.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, to use the new syntax you must use a subset of valid symbols. Numbers aren't that, and as Mu points out, there are other restrictions as well.

Comment: Wrong. `:$set` and `:@pancakes` are valid symbols but you can't say `$set: ...` or `@pancakes: ...`.

Comment: @muistooshort Mm yes, good point.